# Using GetBBSID() within Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
import android.net.wifi;
public class checker extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tvSSID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSSID);
String ssid = WifiInfo.getBSSID();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checker);
    tvSSID.setText(ssid);
}
```

}

I am trying to get the MAC Address with the getBSSID() command. However, I continue to get an error stating thatI cannot assign a dynamic varriable (getBSSID()) to a static String. What else do I need to do in order to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to get wifi service and use service.getConnectionInfo() to get the WifiInfo object.

```
WifiManager wifi_service = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifi_service.getConnectionInfo();
String ssid = wifiInfo.getBSSID();
```

And of course you need to put above code inside the onCreate() block.